# Only one DbManager for many Objects

Tags: php, oop

I'm building a big OOP Based PHP project, I've written 2 classes User and Page :

```
class User{

//user properties
  private $_id,
          $_name,
          $_email;
//constructor
   public function __construct(){}

//getters and setters
   public function setId($id){
     $this->$_id=$id;
   }

    public function setName($name){
     $this->$_name=$name;
   }

    public function setId($email){
     $this->$_email=$email;
   }

   public function getId(){
    return $this->_id;
   }

   public function getName(){
    return $this->_name;
   }

  public function getEmail(){
    return $this->_email;
   }
}

class Page{
   //properties
   private $_id,
           $_title;

   //constructor
   public function __construct(){}

   //getters and setters

   public function setId($id){
     $this->_id=$id;
   }

   public function setTitle($title){
      $this->_title=$title
   }

   public function getId(){
     return $this->_id;
   }

   public function getTitle(){
     return $this->_title;
   }

}
```

As you can conclude , I need to add another class DBManager containing add, edit, delete , list and views methods .

I don't know how to create a method (add for instance) in the class DBManager, that can add Users and Pages. without creating a class Manager for every class.

in other words , I want to create a class DBManager for all my objects.. instead of creating something like :

```
class User : class UserManager
class Page : class PageManager
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: I have two classes, user and page, I want to create only one DBManager for the two classes, so I can use the add function in DBManager , not only to add a user to the database, But also to add a page to database.

Comment: so Instead of creating 2 DBManagers, UserManager and PageManager , with 2 methods add(array $user) and add(array $page) , I want to have one class with one method add(),which can add a user or page to the db

Comment: Create a DBManager class with options in the construct (for table name, etc) - and create a HAS-A relationship between User and DBManager, and Page and DBManager? - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Has-a

Comment: Thank you @Lamanna, I will read that

Comment: I can't +1 cuz I'm new to this website :))